# Blackberry Developers Alpha Device Drivers

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks

I have BB 10 Developers Alpha device. Due to some reason I had to swipe whole data from the device (Swipe data option from Settings). But after that I am not able to connect my device to BB desktop manager. Also all the default icons on Home screen are gone, except Browser.

I tried the suggestions from -

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/BB10-Dev-Alpha-Device-Driver-or-how-to-restore-the-OS/td-p/1735097

But to no avail. How can I get back the device to normal state. Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had the same problem.

1. Go [here](https://developer.blackberry.com/blackberry10devalphas/update)
2. Download "Dev Alpha autoloader" at the bottom of page
3. Do all instructions

And **Enjoy**!